# Relative import doesn't work for no reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I've made a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130026/make-button-execute-a-script) and the user [@eyllanesc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc) literally just rewrote in a proper way, organizing it in three files (gui.py, cli.py and lib.py). **The thing is that imports in gui.py and cli.py don't work**. I've done research, tried a lot of things and the code is, as far as I can see, correct and all three files are in same folder.

This is the only line of code you need to reproduce the error:

```
from lib import organize_folder
```

Nothing I tried changed the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\cli.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lib import organize_folder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

**Do you have ideas of where this come from?
How could I resolve this?**

Comment: Where is `lib.py` located, in relation to your current directory?

Comment: @Błotosmętek, they'r all in same directory

Comment: @O'Schell That's better, but keep going. Remove stuff until you have only what you need to reproduce the problem. See [mre] for instructions.

Comment: It's never *"for no reason"* - if you want to become a good programmer, remove this phrase from your vocabulary. There is always a reason when code doesn't work.

Comment: @kaya3 Receveid 5/5

Comment: @wjandrea I think it's fine with this

Comment: @O'Schell If that's all you need, then we can get rid of the other stuff. I edited your post for you, to make that clear :) Now onto the problem, try `os.getcwd()` to make sure you're in the right place, try `'lib.py' in os.listdir()` to make sure your lib is there (should be True), and check `sys.path` to confirm the CWD is in the path.

Comment: @wjandrea: 'lib.py' in os.listdir() print "False" ; os.getcwd() print C:\Users\myusername and when the file are in C:\, sys.path shows it as WindowsPath('C:/')]

Comment: @O'Schell You're in the wrong place. Are you running those commands interactively? Cause you need to put them in the script for them to help with diagnosing.

Comment: @wjandrea [They are in the scripts](https://photos.app.goo.gl/WgvBWjshF2EJ58ud8)

Comment: @O'Schell Hmm, `sys.path` should only have strings. Your code had some stuff that put a `Path` in `sys.path`, but from what you said I inferred that you took it out. You need to go back to the drawing board and confirm that you have a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea  What do you mean ? the minimal reproducible example is the one line you have up there. I've tried it by deleting all my code but this particular line in cli and gui... Image of it are in the google photo thing

Comment: @O'Schell OK I looked at the pictures. What IDE is that? It looks like the main problem is that the IDE is running the script interactively and not changing the CWD, which makes `'C:\\'` inaccessible. you do have `WindowsPath('C:/')` in `sys.path` but that's useless cause it needs to be a string.

Comment: See the documentation for [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: ok @wjandrea, looking at it with another IDE

Comment: Works... HUGE THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my IDE (from Pyzo to Atome) and it was solve
Huge thanks to @wjandrea for the help !